# Plural Iterator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext2

This is the code its working fine only the words ending with s,x,z are not being picked up

```
import re
def plural(noun):
    for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules:
        if matches_rule(noun):
            return apply_rule(noun)

def build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace):
    def matches_rule(word):
        return re.search(pattern,word)
    def apply_rule(word):
        return re.sub(search, replace, word)
    return (matches_rule, apply_rule)

def rules(rules_filename):
    with open(rules_filename, encoding='utf-8') as pattern_file:
        for line in pattern_file:
            pattern, search, replace = line.split(None, 3)
            yield build_match_and_apply_functions(pattern, search, replace)
def plural(noun, rules_filename='plurals.txt'):
    for matches_rules, apply_rule in rules(rules_filename):
        if matches_rules(noun):
            return apply_rule(noun)
    raise ValueError('no matching rule for {0}'.format(noun))

r3 = plural('tax')
print(r3)
```

And this is the rules file

```
[sxz]$               $    es
[^aeioudgkprt]h$     $    es
[^aeiou]y$          y$    ies
$                    $    s
```

I am executing this code on sublime text 2. Can anyone find out the error ?

Comment: I just ran your code and it seems to work fine. "tax"->"taxes", "ranch"->"ranches", "duck"->"ducks", "sky"->"skies"

Comment: are you using sublime text 2 also for testing ?

Comment: Nope. So if we rule out problems in your python code itself and assume it is a problem _specifically_ with sublime text, you should probably tag it with that.